# Should I make http requests in Activity, then pass data to Fragment? Or make requests directly in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have application where I have Activity with few Fragments. In that state it's easy. In Activity, using retrofit I make request to REST API, get data then pass it to Fragments using bundle. (Passing list of my objects using bundle was a little pain, but manageable)

Problem starts when I want refresh data in Fragment every x seconds. With described solution I'd have to recreate Fragment with every request, which is ... stupid.

So I have 2 ideas:

1. make all requests to REST API in Fragment. But I have no idea if it's considered as good solution.
2. make all requests in Activity and exchange data using EventBus library.  (http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

Can you please tell me if one of those ideas is good, or should I do something completely different? Or can you tell me pros and cons of different approaches?

Thanks a lot for answers!

Comment: I suggest you read https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0. They use MVP which also helps in mock testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your fragments loosely coupled with activity so that it can be used with other activities. According to Google -

In order to reuse the Fragment UI components, you should build each as a completely self-contained, modular component that defines its own layout and behavior. Once you have defined these reusable Fragments, you can associate them with an Activity and connect them with the application logic to realize the overall composite UI.

Read more - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html?hl=ru

It is better to request network data from Fragment. Also if you have any dependency of the data in your activity which is received from the network call then you can also use callbacks to send that data back to activity

Comment: Makes sense! I'll do it in fragments

Comment: @R4v0 - Please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have service for HTTP calls. You can make async calls from service, and implement listener interface at your activity or fragment. Than that listener can interact with view.

Comment: Can you point me somewhere is good example how to implemented such service?

Answer (score 0):

I usually agree with MmtBkn, but since you use Retrofit, I think it is at least not a bad practice to perform HTTP requests from the UI class. And in my opinion you should make these requests from the Fragment, because it contains the views where the loaded content will be displayed. If you think about placing the Fragment in another Activity, you would end up with duplicate code that performs the HTTP request and sends the data to the Fragment via event bus.